# R System Call with Multiple Python Commands

Tags: python, r

I need to pass multiple python commands into one system call (in R), and I am having difficulty with the syntax.

What I'm trying to combine:

```
system("python "file1.py" -f "module_to_load1.py" -o "output_loc_file1"")
system("python "file2.py" -f "module_to_load2.py" -o "output_loc_file2"")
```

Simplified code:

```
 pystr="python -c print('hi')"
 system(paste(pystr, " && ", pystr, sep=""))
```

My desired output is:

```
hi
hi
```

If I enter the code directly into the command prompt, I get the desired output:

```
python -c print('hi') && python -c print('hi')

>> hi
>> hi
```

However, the system call is only returning a single 'hi', and I can't figure out what my dumb error is.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're better off storing it as a script than trying to manage a messy system call:

file: my.py

```
print "hi"
print "hi"
```

Then from R:

```
> system("python my.py")
hi
hi
```

In the case that your actual code is much more complicated, you can generate python code and write it to a file that you then call.

Comment: I'll have to think on that a bit - my real code is calling two python files, each using argparse as well (I added full code to question for clarity).  I could make a my.py that has two system calls in series - is that would you'd suggest?

Comment: Import all `.py` as modules in a `master.py` and run that in single `system()` call.

Comment: @r-noob exactly. Just roll it up into one. This simplifies the call from R and avoids the hassle of figuring out the quotes as explained by Dirk.

Comment: Thank you for your help - I'll beef up my scripts on the python side to avoid having to bandaid it in R.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just line up quotes like that -- embedded quotes need to be escaped.  So instead of

```
system("python "file1.py" -f "module_to_load1.py" -o "output_loc_file1"")
```

do

```
system("python \"file1.py\" -f \"module_to_load1.py\" -o \"output_loc_file1\"")
```

or simply omit the quotes as the filenames do not contain troublesome characters:

```
system("python file1.py -f module_to_load1.py -o output_loc_file1")
```

The recommendation about writing proper Python scripts is still a good one.